# How to reinstall corrupted Android applications with ease?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, external-sd, system-freeze

The other day I woke up, my Android phone was frozen and only removing the battery helped to reset it. It looks like overnight something terribly went wrong as the memory card was not readable anymore and even after formatting it, it got a few bad sectors in the report.

I have about 150 applications installed and some of them which were moved to the memory card obviously do not work anymore. I had backup of my data but not the apps, as I thought I could always download them again. However, I can not find an easy way to do it. First of all, the corrupt applications still show up under settings/applications/manage applications, but the only way I can tell if they are missing or not is that their icon is some default Android robot with an SD card next to it and the names are not human friendly but more like `com.biggu.shopsavvy`.

I tried different apps to solve the problem, but I could not find any which would be better than doing it manually. What I need is to either reinstall all apps with a tap of a one button or install a list of apps in batch from the market.

Comment: with 150 apps you just needed 1 more .  They have apps for android that do "application backup and restore" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup&hl=en  Although it is probably to late to apply such things, I thought it was very usefull for me to control what is on at the time, and backup.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install the missing apps would probably to go to the Play Store on a PC and queue them up for install on the device.

You will still have to look on the device and see which ones you need to reinstall; there isn't a way to simplify that process. Looking at them the way you are, for the ones that have the "default icon" and the SD card is probably the easiest way to identify them. The "non-friendly" name that you see can be used to search in the Google Play Store and you will be able to find the app from that.

Or you can append it to the end of the "details" URL like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.biggu.shopsavvy
```

That will take you directly to the shop savvy app, then you can install it to the device.

Comment: "there isn't a way to simplify that process": Meanwhile there is: My tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) a.o. creates such a list, and even links the apps to their resp. store (i.e. Google Play, F-Droid, etc.). Requires only Bash and ADB. Confirmed to run on Linux, Mac and Windows (via Cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

Download the apk files and re-install them. I recommend this website: www.apkpure.com

Comment: What makes that a better choice than simply pushing them from the Play Store's web UI, as Ryan recommended? Installing from "unknown sources" should only be done if you can be sure to trust those sources. You write nothing about how trustable your source is. Could you please [edit] your post an elaborate a little on that? There are far too many "bad sites" out there, where you get "modified APKs" you'd better kept your fingers off.

Comment: While I do trust APKPure, I agree on @Izzy 's part that it doesn't solve the problem. It's only a way to get apps when they're not available on Play, not a full-fledged Play alternative.